# Standalone IE installer?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

[I have been trying to use this IE11 installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-11-for-windows-7-details.aspx) labeled `Internet Explorer 11 for IT Professionals and Developers--Windows 7 64-bit Edition and Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit Edition (recommended)`, to upgrade IE9->IE11 on multiple PCs.

I try with the arguments `/quiet /update-no /norestart` as [documented here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321443.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). And yet it still fails with errors pertaining to updates:

```
00:04.524: WARNING: PauseAUThread: Failed to resume Automatic Updates: 0x80070005
00:04.555: INFO:    Setup exit code: 0x00009C47 (40007) - 
00:04.586: INFO:    Cleaning up temporary files in: C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1BD19.tmp
00:04.711: INFO:    Unable to remove directory C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1BD19.tmp, marking for deletion on reboot.
00:04.727: INFO:    Released Internet Explorer Installer Mutex
```

Is there a full standalone installer so it doesn't attempt updates to make automated deployment more reliable?

Google seems to indicate this error is as permission issue, but this is running under domain & local admin (both the user deploying it and any possible user logged in).

Answer (score 1):

What you have *is* the full installer (it should be around 50MB in size).

Even though the installer is "standalone", it is still a Microsoft update (.msu) at it's core, not an independent MSI application.  As such, it requires Windows Update to be working properly.  The error you are seeing in the log is probably due to some other update that is pending, or Windows Updates being broken in general.

Basically, the error code (0x80070005) is an access denied error, which means it failed to update some file or registry setting that it expected to have access to.  It should have prompted for elevation when you ran it.  If you are not logged on as an admin, the prompt won't happen if UAC is off.  If you are logged on as an admin, it shouldn't matter if UAC is on or off, but try right-clicking it and hitting "Run as Administrator" anyway and see if that helps.

[This MS KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968003) might be helpful also.  It contains a script that grants the Administrator account access to the central registry hives and Windows directories (in case permissions are broken).

Comment: I'm running it as full domain admin with the switch `/quiet` so no prompts will happen either way

Comment: How are you deploying it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284023/wmiclass-create-returning-variables